# Typescript 4.6.4 tsconfig.json target

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have just upgraded to Typescript 4.6.4 and in the tsconfig.json file I wanted to update the target to es2022 but I am getting this error. Is there a setting in vs2019 that I need to change for this to work?

> Severity   Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
> Error       Build:Argument for '--target' option must be 'ES3', 'ES5', or 'ES2015'. C:\WebProjects\ITF\Web\tsc  OrderTemplateTool.Web

```
PS C:\WebProjects\ITF\Web> tsc -version
Version 4.6.4
```

Angular 12 installed

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exclusive to Visual Studio.

Right click the project in Solution Explorer and then click **Properties** -> **TypeScript Build** under **General**. There you can set **ES Version** and **module system**.

If this does not help try adding: `"compileOnSave": true,` to your tsconfig.json.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the tsconfig for this properties to be used?